# Update other nodes when the transaction is completed

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm learning Firebase in android and I'm trying to make a room system with their respective slots. As in this case several users may want to access the same slot at the same time I decided to use Firebase transactions.

So when the user tries to log in to the slot I do:

```
mySlotRef1.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
                    @Override
                    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
                        Slot p = mutableData.getValue(Slot.class);
                        if (p == null) {
                            return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                        }
                        if (p.getState().equals("closed")) {
                            return Transaction.abort();
                        }

                        // Set value and report transaction success
                        Slot sl1 = new Slot("slot1", idRoom, auth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName(), auth.getCurrentUser().getUid(), "closed", Profile.getCurrentProfile().getProfilePictureUri(200, 200).toString());
                        mutableData.setValue(sl1);
                        return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b,
                                           DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        // Transaction completed
                        Log.d(TAG, "postTransaction:onComplete:" + databaseError);

                    }
                });
```

I think this works, i. e. when the slot is closed it only enters one user and rejects the others in the "Slot" ref. But **the problem is that I also need to update two more values in the "User" directory** and I can't find a way to do it "only when the user occupied the slot", that is, when the transaction was completed.

**UPDATE**:
This is the part where I check to see if the slot is open.

```
mySlotRef1.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    Slot data = dataSnapshot.getValue(Slot.class);
                                    state = data.getState();
                                    if (state.equals("open")) {
                                        saveSlot(slot);
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Slot not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                }

                            });
```

Answer (score 1):

This not how things are working when it comes to concurent writes. None of your slots will be closed. When you are using transactions, it means that every write that will be made in the same time by different users will be made in different thread of execution. So using transactions, it doesn't matter if two or many other users will make a write operation in the same time, you'll have a correct result.

If you want to update otrher fields within another class, just put your logic inside `onComplete()` method. This method is triggered once the transaction is complete.

Comment: I did this in onComplete(): 
Map updates = new HashMap();
updates.put("/Users/" + auth.getCurrentUser().getUid() + "/state", "on");
updates.put("/Users/" + auth.getCurrentUser().getUid() + "/idroom", idRoom);
myRef1.updateChildren(updates);

Comment: But when trying to occupy the slot with two users, it performs the update on both of them. I mean, both users get like "on" with the "idroom"

Comment: That's correct, because every user uses a separate transaction, which in term means that `onComplete()` method is called for each one of them. This how transactions works. But what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to achieve that only one user of all those who try to occupy the slot can do it. As a result, only the "state" and "idroom" of the occupying user is updated

Comment: In this case you need to create a condition. You need to verify if the user  who's trying to access the slot is the actual user you want it to be able to do.

Comment: That thing you mention, I think I'm already doing it. Please check the update on my question and tell me what you think

Comment: Ok, but this has nothing to do with transactions. If that code helps you achieve what you want, then use it.